# You don't have permission

Tags: ubuntu

i am a beginner at using emacs. In computer/etc/ i have dante.conf, i want to change proxy settings there but  after changing proxy settings i can't save that file, it says that i don't have permission. As i told you i am absolutely beginner and i ask you to help me with this problem (and please can you write it step by step, because i don't understand some commands (where to write them for example)). Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo`? It's probably owned by root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your terminal, open the file as administrator, for example :

```
sudo emacs -nw /etc/dante.conf
```

Then do your changes, save with ctrl + X, ctrl + S and quit with ctrl + X, ctrl + C.

Comment: No problem, you should mark the answer as accepted if it did solve your problem.

Comment: can you help me with my problem xd? 

Until now i used windows,on windows to watch football games online i used proxifier, but now i am using ubuntu, so to watch games i an trying to use dante-client as proxifier, i have changed proxy settings in dante.conf as you said and now i don't know what to do next Thank you.

Comment: Hm that's a different question, no idea, you should open a new question, as for football matches I get them here : http://livefootballvideo.com/fullmatch :)